# Fastest way to find linearly independent columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a rectangular matrix $X$ of size $n\times m$ with $m>n$, what is the fastest way to find the linearly independent coloums.

Robust methods like SVD or RRQR decompostion have complexity of order $O(n^3)$ for square  matrices.

Can we do this in linear time or at least quadratic e.g. $O(n^2)$.

Comment: But f it is full rank, aren't you done?

Comment: Wouldn't Gaussian elimination tell you that? Just look for nonzero pivots

Comment: @Bey i know Gaussian ellimination, SVD and QR can solve the problem but complexity is very high. I am interested in a fast method?

Comment: @Gray i have remove the last condition now. My actual question was that i some how know that the matrix is full rank but i dont know which columns are independent.?

Comment: @VInayakArbol the condition makes sense, I think that zed didn't notice the $m>n$ condition.

Comment: @VinayakAbrol in general there is no such algorithm. Gauss-Jordan reduction is the best general algorithm. However if ur matrix has special structure then there are much better algorithms out there.